# @MessageMapping in Spring how does it work internally

Tags: spring, spring-integration

The annotation @MessageMapping is used for listening to a queue.
I want to know how Spring maps the method to any custom listener.

Comment: MessageMapping messageMappingAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, MessageMapping.class); 
Is this the  code?